# Adding new records to remote data when results not found - select2

Tags: jquery-select2

I have a textbox where I utilise the [select2](https://select2.github.io) library.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="tags" class="control-label">Tags</label>
    <select class="tagsSearch" class="form-control" ng-model="post.tags" id="tags" style="width: 100%">
    </select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".tagsSearch").select2({
placeholder: 'Search for tags',
delay: 250,
tags: true,
multiple: true,
tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
minimumInputLength: 2,
minimumResultsForSearch: 1,
ajax: {
    url: function (params) {
        return '/api/searchTags';
    },
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    data: function (params) {
        return {
            text: params.term 
        };
    },
    processResults: function(data){
        return{
            results: $.map(data, function(obj){
            return {
                id: obj.name, text: obj.name
            };
          })
        };
    }}
});
```

This works really as I get the **/api/searchTags** API triggered to find new fields to autofill. When a match is not found, the user has an option to create a new one.

I want to be able to add this newly selected text to the remote datasource via an API, for example:

/api/addToTags

However, do I trigger that event?

Alternatively, I can also "mark" these unmatched fields so that when the form is submitted, I can look for these marked fields and make an API with that instead.

I hope this is clear enough. Any input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get all tags in input on 'change' event and you can check on the server which tag is already exist

```
$(".tagsSearch").select2({
    placeholder: 'Search for tags',
    delay: 250,
    tags: true,
    multiple: true,
    tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    minimumResultsForSearch: 1,
    ajax: {
         url: function (params) {
            return '/api/searchTags';
         },
         dataType: "json",
         type: "GET",
         data: function (params) {
            return {
                text: params.term 
         };
    },
    processResults: function(data){
        return{
            results: $.map(data, function(obj){
            return {
                id: obj.name, text: obj.name
            };
          })
        };
    }}
})
.on('change', function(e){
    // $(this).val() - array of tags in input
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/api/addToTags',
            data: {
                tags: JSON.stringify($(this).val())
            },
            success: function (json) {
                 console.log(json);
            }
        });
});
```

**or alternatively**
Do not allow user to create tags what started with a number by method cteateTag. And then on 'change' you will be able to separate new and exist tags. If you get a number this will be mean you get id of exist tag

```
$(".tagsSearch").select2({
    placeholder: 'Search for tags',
    delay: 250,
    tags: true,
    multiple: true,
    tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    minimumResultsForSearch: 1,
    ajax: {
         url: function (params) {
            return '/api/searchTags';
         },
         dataType: "json",
         type: "GET",
         data: function (params) {
            return {
                text: params.term 
         };
    },
    // do not allow user to create tag with a number
    createTag: function (params) {
        if (/^\d+$/.test(params.term)) {
            return null;
        }
        return {id: params.term, text: params.term, newTag: true};
    }
    processResults: function(data){
        return{
            results: $.map(data, function(obj){
            return {
                id: obj.name, text: obj.name
            };
          })
        };
    }}
})
.on('change', function(e){
    // $(this).val() - array of tags in input

    var allTags = $(this).val();
    var newTags = [];
    allTags.forEach(function (el) {
        if (!parseInt(el)){ // if it is not NaN it is a new tag, in the other case this will be id of exist tag
            newTags.push(el);
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/api/addToTags',
            data: {
                tags: JSON.stringify(newTags)
            },
            success: function (json) {
                 console.log(json);
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the .on Change method. However, the problem is that I will be searching for tags that are already in the tags collection, as they were selected from the dropdown. What I am looking for is a way where when I select a text from a dropdown, I don't trigger the /addToTags. However, when I type up a new one and select that one instead, I want to be able to trigger /addToTags. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Why is my second solution not suitable for you? You can add one more array in global scope for tags, for which /addToTags have been already used and trigger /addTags only for latest new tag

Comment: I will test it out but I do need to support all types of text, including numbers. Thanks for your help so far mate.